# UIScrollView scrolls to top and becomes unscrollable

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, scrollview

Hey guys I have a `UIScrollView` that contains a large view with a bunch of input fields.

Everything scrolls fine until you change a textfield, modify a label's text. Once that happens the scroll view scrolls to the top and becomes un-scrollable. I suspect something with autolayout is breaking this, but I cannot track down the issue. Has anyone experienced this before?

[image: i.imgur.com/oXhZnLV.png]

[image: i.imgur.com/ccwMvWr.png]

This is scrolled down so I know the constraint is off here, this is just to show the exact field breaking it.

Comment: Take a screenshot of your layout - thatll hey us see if the layout has been constrained properly.

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/oXhZnLV.png

Comment: http://imgur.com/ccwMvWr.png this is scrolled down so I know the constraint is off here, this is just to show the exact field breaking it.

Comment: please add these to OP instead of comments.

Comment: If its "breaking" when a field or label is being changed, it may be that the fields themselves are not constrained to the correct view.

Comment: Trailing and leading are to superview, top is the label above it.